# REDIS - 'slave-priority' setting

Tags: redis

I'm setting for REDIS Replication. (1 master - 3 slaves & 1 sentinel )

and I edited Master's configuration like this.

**slave-priority 10** (another redis's setting is 100 - default)

then I killed master, the other slave was promoted to MASTER.
After startup previous master again, I killed current master.
(I expected previous master would be prompted to MASTER. 
because that server's slave-priority is lower than everything else..)

but another slave was prompted to MASTER, not original master..
(original's master slave-priority setting was changed to default '100' automatically...)

Do you know why happen this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is good answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351045/is-master-always-redis-instance-with-smallest-priority

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old problem but I encountered something like this on redis 6.2.6. I was wanting to keep the slave-priority at 0 but sentinel was changing it to 100. my solution was to use **replica-priority 0**

It seems redis sentinel was changing it because i was using **slave-priority 0** in the conf file. Sentinel was then changing it to **replica-priority 100** in the conf file. Oddly, **info replication** in the cli returns the value as slave_priority not replica-priority.